# AsyncTask - onProgressUpdate not called until after doInBackground completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have searched other posts but haven't found any describing my particular problem.  Many of them refer to calling publishProgress from doInBackground.  I am calling publishProgress from onPreExecute expecting a dialog to be displayed to inform a user that data is being fetched.  The AsyncTask is being launched from the user making a selection from a Spinner.  Rather than the dialog being displayed, the UI freezes until the AsyncTask completes.  I have added in log messages and it appears that although publishProgress is called in onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate is not being executed until after doInBackground is completed.

The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner spinner;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter<String>(this, new String[]{"one", "two", "three"});
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    try{
        FetchDataTask fetchDataTask = new FetchDataTask();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            fetchDataTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "data");
        } else{
            fetchDataTask.execute("data");
        }
        fetchDataTask.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    private  final String TAG = FetchDataTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private  final Integer FETCHING_DATA = 1;

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d(TAG,"Exiting onPostExecute");     
        dialog.dismiss();       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        publishProgress(FETCHING_DATA);
        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching", "Data");
        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting onProgressUpdate");

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        /*
         *  Fetching data here
         */

        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting doInBackground");
        countDownLatch.countDown();
        return true;
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException{
        countDownLatch.await();
    }

}
}
```

The Spinner:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter<T> implements SpinnerAdapter {

Context context;
T[] values;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, T[] values){
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    for(T value: this.values){
        Log.d("Spinner", value.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return values[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView v = new TextView(context);
    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    v.setText(values[position].toString());
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

}
```

The view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am think this might have something to do with executing the AsyncTask from the Spinner selection because simply executing it in the Activity without connecting it to the Spinner does not have this problem.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You dont keep on showing dialog  on progress update, instead you show it `onPreExecute` update it `onProgressUpdate` and hide it `onPostExecute` or `cancel`. and in your case you dont need the publish progress since progressBar is indefinite

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting onPreExecute");
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Fetching", "Data");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting doInBackground");
        countDownLatch.countDown();
        //publishProgress(x);
        return true;
    }

    public void await() throws InterruptedException
    {
        countDownLatch.await();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.d(TAG, "Exiting onProgressUpdate");
        // update progressbar value
        // ex progresssBar.setProgress(values[0]);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.d(TAG,"Exiting onPostExecute");     
        dialog.dismiss();       
    }
```

Comment: This isn't fixing the issue.  I am making sure to sleep in doInBackground for 5 seconds.  This should leave lots of time for the dialog to show but still the dialog shows after exiting doInBackground and is dismissed immediately.